# How to read messages from GSM modem in Embedded C?

Tags: c, arduino, embedded, arduino-uno, gsm

I am currently working on my mini-project under the domain "Internet of Things". I chose to design a wireless Notice board using a GSM module.

I divided the project into two modules. First, the Arduino-LED board interface which perfectly completed.

Second, GSM-Arduino interface. Basically, a message/SMS will be sent from the mobile phone to the GSM module and then we have to read that message from GSM module using Arduino. I am facing a problem here. The message is being sent to the GSM modem but I am not able to read it. I tried writing different codes, but its not working. The message is not being displayed.

Here is the code snippet I tried.

```
`#include SoftwareSerial.h

SoftwareSerial SIM900A(2,3);// RX | TX

// Connect the SIM900A TX to Arduino pin 2 RX 

// Connect the SIM900A RX to Arduino pin 3 TX.


void setup()
{ 

      SIM900A.begin(9600);   // Setting the baud rate of GSM Module 

      Serial.begin(9600);    // Setting the baud rate of Serial Monitor(Arduino)

      Serial.println ("SIM900A Ready");

      delay(100);

      Serial.println (" Press s to send and r to recieve ");

}

 void loop()
 {

     if (Serial.available()>0)

     switch(Serial.read())

     {

       case 's':  SendMessage();
               break;

       case 'r':  RecieveMessage();
               break;

      }

    if (SIM900A.available()>0)

        Serial.write(SIM900A.read());

}


 void SendMessage()
{

     SIM900A.println("AT+CMGF=1");    //Sets the GSM Module in Text Mode

     delay(1000);  // Delay of 1000 milli seconds or 1 second

     Serial.println ("Set SMS Number");

     SIM900A.println("AT+CMGS=\"+91xxxxxxxxxx\"\r"); //Replace with your mobileno.

     delay(1000);

     Serial.println ("Set SMS Content");

    SIM900A.println("Hello, I am SIM900A GSM Module");// The SMS text you want to send

     delay(100);

     Serial.println ("Finish");

     SIM900A.println((char)26);// ASCII code of CTRL+Z

     delay(1000);

     Serial.println (" ->SMS Sent");
}


 void RecieveMessage()
{

     Serial.println ("SIM900A Receiving SMS");

     delay (1000);

     SIM900A.println("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0"); // AT Command to receive a live SMS

     delay(1000);

     Serial.write (" ->Unread SMS Recieved");

 }`
```

Comment: We don't evn know if your hardware works.  We can't help with hardware debugging.  What do you see with a scope on the lines?

Comment: The hardware works fine! When we insert a SIM card in the GSM module and test it whether it is receiving any message when sent from a mobile phone, its completely working. How to read the receive message is where I am facing problem. I am not able to read the message from GSM.

Comment: 'test it whether it is receiving any message' - how do you test it if you cannot receive any data on your Arduino interface?

Answer (score 2):

You might have to set the preferred SMS storage to SIM card using the command:

```
SIM900A.print("AT+CPMS=\"SM\"\r");
```

Also, move this command to setup():

```
SIM900A.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");
```

Lastly, note how I have used SIM900A.print() instead of SIM900A.println() and send a '\r' or 0x0d after each command. println() sends a "\n\r" and that causes problems in some modems.

Comment: You might also want to verify that the baud rate of the modem is 9600 or something else. Most modems let you configure this, so it may have been changed to some other value